# Asynchronicity, threading, node.js and Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asynchronous, node.js, runtime, event-driven

Aside from using a different scripting language, it seems that the main appeal of node.js is it's support for event-driven programming which makes it easier to write scalable servers (or other typically I/O bound applications) due to its simplified non-blocking I/O calls.  However, this feature comes at the expense of having to learn a new programming model which essentially requires you to pass callback after callback function making some straightforward tasks (e.g. dependent sequences of actions) a bit more complicated.

Contrast that programming model to the traditional one of Ruby on Rails which blocks on all I/O operations and is (effectively) single-threaded (due to MRI's green thread implementation).

Just dreaming out loud here, it seems that it should be possible to implement a Ruby (or Rails) runtime which reconciles these models by trapping I/O calls, transparently replacing them with their non-blocking version, storing the current continuation and calling it when the I/O operation is complete.  This way you would get the familiar, procedural programming style and the benefits of the event-driven/asynchronous/callback model.

Is such a runtime (or runtime translator) technically possible?  Are there web frameworks that do something like this already?

Comment: Illya Grigorik has done some work with ruby fibers, EventMachine and rails. Take a look at this (especially the links at the bottom): https://github.com/igrigorik/async-rails

Comment: @igorw: that looks very much what I was thinking about, please post it as an answer so I can upvote!

Comment: Making rails asynchronous seems like a hack to me. That defiantly looks like an abstraction that's going to leak badly.

Comment: instead of `node.js`consider using EventMachine which is pure Ruby

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @igorw, the [async-rails](https://github.com/igrigorik/async-rails) project is what I was imagining.

But as @Raynos and @apneadiving point out, there are potentially better solutions such as [Ruby EventMachine](http://rubyeventmachine.com/) and [stormjs](https://github.com/guileen/stormjs).

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

There are two possibilities for doing asynchronous but imperative programming

**Use a real asynchronous language:**

Erlang would be an example where you can write imperative do this, do that code and it translates to async. I don't think it goes all the way though.

**Use a compiler**

You can use a compiler that converts blocking style code into non-blocking code. I personally *highly* recommend against this because it's a black box and a nightmare to debug.

One example would be [storm](https://github.com/guileen/stormjs)

> However, this feature comes at the expense of having to learn a new programming model which essentially requires you to pass callback after callback function making some straightforward tasks (e.g. dependent sequences of actions) a bit more complicated.

I however recommend that you bite the bullet and make the paradigm switch. This will be a far better investment in the long-run. Mind you it's not neccessary to use node.js, there are strong alternatives like erlang and haskell out there.